# PaperclipOpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden) with Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have images stored in S3 with Paperclip and this error is intermittenly showing up. I had it resolved a few weeks ago by upgrading to ruby 2.1.5, but it's back now.

Here's my controller code:

```
  def download
    extension = File.extname(@gallery_photo.image_file_name)
    send_data open("#{@gallery_photo.image.expiring_url(10, :original)}").read, filename: "original_#{@gallery_photo.id}#{extension}", type: @gallery_photo.image_content_type
  end
```

Here's the error:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):
```

Rails 4 & Ruby 2.1.5

Comment: I'm having the same issue, only for some photos... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to extend the `expiring_url` to 10000.

Comment: can you please tell me why have you extended from 10 to 10000, also i want my link to expire in 10 secs what should give

Comment: For whatever reason, my setup was taking longer than 10 seconds to fetch the image. This app can occasionally load 500+ images on a page. Otherwise, I'm sure I could have gotten away with a much smaller number.

Comment: Preacher is absolutely correct! All this time, I couldn't figure out why permissions weren't working correctly...but they were. I dropped mine down to 300 (5 mins). I would definitely experiment more, but 10sec is a no go.