# How to download a file with Rails 4 Paperclip using s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a project that upload files attachments with paperclip and s3. How can I have users download these files.

Model

```
class Assets
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

Routes

```
resources :assets do
  member do
    get 'download'
  end
end
```

Controller

```
  def download
    data = open(@asset.file.url)
    send_data data.read, :type => data.content_type, :x_sendfile => true, :url_based_filename => true
  end
```

Error:

OpenURI::HTTPError in AssetsController#download

403 Forbidden

Comment: There are countless resources on the web and SO that cover this.  Suggest you look at these first, attempt to do this yourself and the post if you get stuck (with code, errors etc).

Comment: I tried different solutions on this and it is not clear to me.

Comment: @steveklein I gave more information on what I was working on

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394881/paperclipopenurihttperror-403-forbidden-with-amazon-s3-storage)

Answer:

```
def download
  extension = File.extname(@asset.file_file_name)
  send_data open("#{@asset.file.expiring_url(10000, :original)}").read, filename: "original_#{@asset.id}#{extension}", type: @asset.file_content_type
end
```